# Convert mongo aggregation query to kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I have below mongodb query, need to convert it to the kotlin spring data. Can any one help me this:

```
db.getCollection('activities').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        day: 1,
        rateQuotes: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$rateQuotes" }, then: { $size: "$rateQuotes" }, else: 0 } }    
    }
}])
```

when "rateQuotes" is an array, following code will work:

```
val aggregation = newAggregation(
     project("day")
     .and("rateQuotes").size().`as`("rateQuotes")
     )
```

need to add the condition to handle null value, I think it should be:

```
val cond = ConditionalOperators.Cond.***
val aggregation = newAggregation(
     project("day")         
     .and("rateQuotes").applyCondition(cond).size().`as`("rateQuotes")
)
```

But I have difficulty to create the condition and apply condition. Not sure if the size should be included in the condition. If anyone has experience for this, please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, like to share the answer here, in case, any one want to do the same thing later:

```js
val rateQuoteConDoc = org.bson.Document("\$isArray", "\$rateQuotes")
val rateQuotesCondition = ConditionalOperators.Cond.`when`{ rateQuoteConDoc }
    .thenValueOf { org.bson.Document("\$size", "\$rateQuotes") }
    .otherwise(0)

val allShipmentsConDoc = org.bson.Document("\$isArray", "\$allShipments.shipments")
val allShipmentsCondition = ConditionalOperators.Cond.`when`{ allShipmentsConDoc }
    .thenValueOf { org.bson.Document("\$size", "\$allShipments.shipments")}
    .otherwise(0)

val match = match(Criteria.where(dayField).gte(startDate).and("type").`is`(type))

val aggregation = newAggregation(
    match,
    project("day")
        .and(rateQuotesCondition).`as`("rateQuotes")
        .and(allShipmentsCondition).`as`("allShipments")
)
```

Thanks!